# Error while creating JAR file and executing it

Tags: java, jar

I have a problem creating and executing a JAR file. I have already made a JAR file, but when I execute it with `java -jar`, I am getting an error `Error: could not find and load main class ...` I make a JAR file with `jar cvfm`, but I execute it from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.70\

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an executable jar file you have to specify the entry point to the jar.Like this:

jar -cvfe "jar file name" "Main Class Name(Ex com.test.MainTest)" "Files to be included in the jar"

If you already have a jar file, you can update the manifest file by creating an "additions" file and running the command to include the main class :

Main-Class: Classname

and run command:
jar ufm "jarfilename" "additions manifest"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an entry in your manifest is missing? You have to add your MainClass to the MANIFEST.MF - the entry needed is `Main-Class: classname`

For mor informations see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we create the jar file , we pass the main-class parameter in Manifest.mf that is embed in the jar .

you have missed that part and now when you are executing its not able to identify the main class to execute from

http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html might help